# Hibernate HQL query analysis tool?

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

Are there any HQL query analysis tools, similar to SQLServer's QueryAnalyser?

I've looked at hiberlyzer in Google Code, which has only one version posted in 2007, with nothing done since then. I've also looked at Hibernate Query Analyzer, also in Google Code, but it only has a profiler, and also suffers from few updates since 2009.

Are there other options I'm not finding?

I have a wild query that I'd like to simplify, but need some help in deciding what's important. (This query generates 85 SQL queries when everything is said and done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Squirrel SQL, and for my purposes it works well...

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

... new versions are coming out fairly regularly